# OpenLayers GeoServer Cross Origin Issue

Tags: proxy, cross-domain, gis, openlayers, geoserver

I am trying to make a WMS GetFeatureInfo request from an openlayers based application to GeoServer. 
But I am hitting the cross origin issue, as it know my origin is http:localhost.

Hopefully someone can help me here is my setup

I have geoserver installed on a windows server with IP x.x.x.x it is accessed via port 8080. 
I have my openlayers application installed locally in IIS 7.5 and I refer to it using

```
http://localhost/Application/Application.html
```

On the GeoServer server I configured the following

GeoServer is installed as part of GeoSuite v2.2, it uses Jetty web service. 
The GeoServer Proxy Extension is installed. (http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GeoServer+Proxy+Extension).

I have set up the rest proxy to use anonymous authentication. I had to do this in config.xml as there is a bug in this version of the GeoServer administration which stops the Authentication filter to be saved. 
I have also ensured that in the rest.properties fileit is configured to allow anonymous authentication.
In the proxy configuration I have allowed localhost

In the openlayers application I set the Proxy Server setting as follows

```
OpenLayers.ProxyServer = "http://x.x.x.x:8080/geoserver/rest/proxy?url="
```

This is still not working, I still get the cross origin issue. I have not set the geoserver 
workspace Base Proxy Url as I am not sure if it is relevant. Do I need to set this? If so to what?

If anyone has solved this please let me know

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Two notes: if possible, run your OpenLayers application from Jetty, and you don't have cross-domain issue. If you have to run it from IIS, you have to set up your proxy also on IIS, not on Jetty.

Comment: Do you know how to do this. Do you have an example. It would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you will need to create a proxy in IIS.  How you do this can vary greatly, there are many ways to do it.  Here's a prebuilt proxy for simplicity.  It should be pretty easy to google more if you need them.  They're a dime a dozen.

- http://netproxy.codeplex.com/

The great news is that the GeoServer 2.3 beta has JSONP support included for GetFeatureInfo requests.  http://blog.geoserver.org/2013/01/29/geoserver-2-3-beta-released/ If you're okay with checking out the bleeding edge, this is the way to go.  You'll no longer need the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

just set [`Base Proxy URL`](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#proxy-base-url) to the one the users use from outside and thus all generated content delivered from geoserver should only supply links using this base and thus avoiding the cross-origin problems.

(in your case you are likely the only (**dev**) user from your machine => set it to `http://localhost:8080/geoserver` ... you could also set it to your machine IP or DNS name if you access it this way for testing)

(for the **prod** install it should maybe be something like `https://example.com/geoserver` or `http://...` if you don't want to secure it outside)

Answer (score -1):

For me, I'm using PHP Curl to act as a proxy, not much to configure, just a page of PHP Curl, then all good to go, no fussy setup. ;)

Regards,
Nas